# toolbar style android:theme custom not applied

Tags: android, styles, toolbar, material-design

i want to customize color of toolbar but changes in custom style for toolbar not work.
i use appcompat 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
in toolbar i set:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:theme="@style/StyleTest"
```

(also i try **app:theme** but these too not effect)
this is my toolbar style:

```
<style name="StyleTest" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

and this style not work.
but when i change my app style items, this also changed in a toolbar (while the toolbar has own style in android:theme value).
for example when i change app style item "textColorSecondary" this also change back arrow in toolbar, but i want different color in toolbar style and app style.
this is app style:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <!-- colorPrimary is a toolbar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#5EB1F7</item>
        <!-- colorAccent color of pressed widget -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/black_half_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <!-- textColorPrimary is a color of the title for Toolbar -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is a color for lollipop system bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_drawer_background</item>
        <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the back arrow and menu
             overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
```

when i change app style items, e.g. colorPrimary or textColorPrimary or textColorSecondary this applied to Toolbar, but toolbar own style is ignored.
How i can apply custom style to toolbar?

Comment: I have the same problem but with TabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:theme` in xml and remove `android:` prefix from StyleTest's properties.

Comment: as you can see, i try app:theme this also no effect. and removing "android:" too

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use style in this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     style="@style/StyleTest" />
```

Baware of `style` without `android:` prefix.